# JUnit version warning on IntelliJ

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run a test method on IntelliJ but when I compile the code I get the warning reported below:

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Failed to parse version of junit:junit: 4.13.1
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.parseVersion(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:54)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:37)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:32)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
```

After this warning the complier build successfully and the test works. (I am using gradle)

Code:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3b7y.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bdWY.png)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLRIW.png)

Comment: have you added `junit-vintage-engine` in your dependencies?

Comment: Please provide a code sample to the issue. Thanks

Comment: I didn't add junit-vintage-engine. How can I add junit-vintage-engine?. I have added the code in the answer. It's my first time that I code a test class on intelliJ

Comment: Do you want to use JUnit 4 or JUnit 5 ? How does your Maven `pom.xml` or Gradle `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: I want to use JUnit 5

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of your code, put the code as text directly in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 declared in your `build.gradle`.

Remove the JUnit 4 dependency:

```
testImplementation('junit:junit:4.13')
```

And re-sync/re-import your project in IntelliJ.